# Program that sum values ​from two lists of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list and dictionaries inside it, I need to add up the values

```
shops = [{'goods': 'apple', 'amount': 400}, {'goods': 'candies', 'amount': 300}, {'goods': 'apple', 'amount': 750}]
```

I need (output):

```
{'apple': 1150, 'candies': 300}
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
output = {}
for good_infos in shops:
    if good_infos['goods'] not in output.keys():
        output[good_infos['goods']] = good_infos['amount']
    else:
        output[good_infos['goods']] += good_infos['amount']
```

Comment: Aye, same thing. Ninja'd!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each item (that is a dict here) in your list with

```
for item in shops:
```

You can then check for the existence of the key within a master dict with

```
if shops[item] in masterDict:
    #Accumulate onto existing sum
else:
    #Declare a new entry


masterDict = {}

for item in shops:
    if item['goods'] in masterDict:
        masterDict[item['goods']] += item['amount']
    else:
        masterDict[item['goods']] = item['amount']
```